# Write HashMap of matrices into a file Java

Tags: java, file, matrix, hashmap

I have created this HashMap where I store (2,1) size matrices.

```
public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<int[][]>> mresults =
 new HashMap<String, ArrayList<int[][]>>();
```

I want to Store this HashMap into a file so that I can send it through Ftp, But at the same upon reception, It should be in a format that allows me to retrieve the matrices easily and be used later.

Any suggestion? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [serialize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) the map. Serialization is a process through which objects can be written to a file and restored at a later time.

Serialize:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("somefile");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(mresults);
oos.close();
fos.close();
```

Restore:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("somefile");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
Map<String, ArrayList<int[][]>> mresults = 
                          (HashMap<String, ArrayList<int[][]>>) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
fis.close();
```

Comment: Thank you. I followed your advice and tried to create a text file as an OutputStream, but I can get some weird symbols written in it. Maybe It's the problem of the file extension, or maybe I didn't store well the matrices?

Comment: @nami The file is not supposed to be human-readable, it is compressed and is only supposed to be used for restoring the object through Java. Serialization is not the right approach if you want a human-readable file.

Comment: No that's fine. It's just that I am not familiar with Serialization so I thought maybe I did a mistake. Thank you very much. That solves my problem :)